# load 5MB of images crashed iPad

Tags: ios, image, memory-management, xamarin.ios

I need to load 5MB of HD images (for iPad) before my game starts up. It crashes somewhere in the loading progress. Well, to confirm it was the 5MB problem, I then tried to load 2.5MB of LD images (iPhone quality) instead. It ran OK, no crashes.

Does it mean that I can't reserve 5MB or more memory? There should be a way to do it.

This happens more frequently when more apps pending in the background. And it doesn't crash if I run my game immediately after a clean reboot. Therefore, it must be a memory problem crashing my game.

Any idea how I can handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5MB of *compressed* image data can easily explose to many (4x-10x) the memory requirements to have them **uncompressed**.

> Any idea how I can handle this?

Use Apple's Instruments and look at memory usage.

Next ensure iOS itself is not caching images (look at the API you're using and their documentation, some will cache, others won't).

Then look if you can dispose of the image earlier. Images can be quite big (and a lot of memory for them is internal to iOS, which is why using Instruments will give you a better picture than MonoTouch's own HeapShot profiler) so disposing it manually (instead of waiting for the GC is generally a good idea).

Also look if you can delay load some images (or at least their decompressed versions), e.g. after the first one(s) are disposed.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for reminding me this point. All the images I got are compressed (png or jpg). Probably I will have to rethink about my memory management tactics.